# Problem in converting a Python code to Delphi

Tags: python, delphi, crc32

I need to convert a Python code to Delphi but I cant.

The Python code is:

```
def crc32(data: bytes, initial):
crc = initial
for x in data:
    for k in range(8):
        if ((crc ^ x) & 0x01) == 1:
            crc = crc >> 1
            crc = crc ^ 0x04c11db7
        else:
            crc = crc >> 1
        x = x >> 1
crc &= 0xffffffff
return crc
```

but when I translate to Delphi code I have a problem, the problem is the line `x = x >> 1`

this is the Delphi code:

```
function TForm1.CalculateCRC32(const data: TBytes; initial: Cardinal): Cardinal;
var
  crc: Cardinal;
  x, z: Integer;
begin
 crc := initial;

 for x in data do
 begin
    for z := 0 to 7 do
    begin
      if ((crc xor x) and $01) = 1 then
      begin
        crc := crc shr 1;
        crc := crc xor $04c11db7;
      end
      else
      begin
       crc := crc shr 1;
      end;

      x := x shr 1; // here its the problem I have
    end;
 end;
 crc := crc and $ffffffff;
 Result := crc;
end;
```

How could I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

I am using Delphi XE11.3

to make a test, I do:

```
data := '123456780000000077000000';
bytedata := HexToBytes(data); //TBytes type

initDataStr := '$FFFFFFFF'; 
initData := Cardinal(StrToInt64(initDataStr));

result := CalculateCRC32(bytedata, initData); //The result should be 7085D2 in hexadecimal.
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You should debug your two programs to see where their behaviours diverge. Did you do that? Please show the details of that debugging.

Comment: Why don't you just use an already availble Pascal CRC32 algo?

Comment: That's none of [any known CRC-32 algorithms](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/17plus.htm).

Comment: You ask *How can I solve this problem?*, but you have not explained what the problem is that you're having. You've not said what's wrong, included any sort of error message, or in any way said what issue it is that you're having here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this way.**

*But you have same basic error in Delphi and Python loop and syntax.*

```
function TForm1.CalculateCRC32(const data: TBytes; initial: Cardinal): Cardinal;
var
  crc, x: Cardinal;
  i, z: Integer;
begin
  crc := initial;

  for i := 0 to High(data) do
  begin
    x := data[i];
    for z := 0 to 7 do
    begin
      if ((crc xor x) and $01) = 1 then
      begin
        crc := crc shr 1;
        crc := crc xor $04c11db7;
      end
      else
      begin
        crc := crc shr 1;
      end;

      x := x shr 1;
    end;
  end;

  crc := crc and $ffffffff;
  Result := crc;
end;
```

I just avoid changing the loop variable x by using the z variable to regulate the bit-wise operations, ensuring the loop functions as intended.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i have the same error message ''Assignment to FOR-Loop variable 'x'

Comment: I just edited my code.